# How does a negative relationship within a cluster effect my prediction error?

Tags: machine-learning, correlation, cross-validation, prediction, clustered-standard-errors

I'm currently a masters student at the university of Leiden and in the middle of my master thesis. In my master thesis I try to find the best way to predict applicant uptake for a vacancy with machine learning techniques as boosting, random forest, neural network and support vector machine. A vacancy can be posted on multiple job boards. As one applicant applies through one job board, it will not apply through another, resulting in a negative correlation between observations within a vacancy.

I know that when observations within a cluster are more similar (positively correlated) the predictive error is seriously underestimated. The underlying structures often leads to dependence structures in the model residuals and the model is likely to overfit as some predictors are often correlated with the underlying dependence structures (Roberts et al., 2017). Roberts and colleagues suggest that for machine learning modeling, block cross-validation need to be implemented to account for the dependency and get estimates that are closer to the true estimates.

I could not find any articles that adress a negative correlation between observations. Do any of you have an idea on how this would effect the fitting of the models?

Link to the article of roberts et al. : http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/ecog.02881/full